# How to find which block displays content?

Tags: block, prestashop

I have to modify a website made by someone else with PrestaShop. I'm just learning how to use that thing...

There is a block displayed on the front page that I can't identify, precisely the one I have to modify (duh!). Is there a simple way to know which one it is and what `.tpl` I have to open in order to change the code?

Comment: Is there any id or class in the html that you can search in the whole code?

Comment: Yeah, not having any answers, that's what I finally did. But searching the code for keywords is not what I inted to do each time I face that particular problem.

Comment: If it's a module you can also try to know what module the html is from, then check the module positions in the back office to get the name of the module. If it's not, it can be harder to find the right template file